# IIS App Pool Idle Time-out Action .NET Framework 4.5.1

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net, iis-8

I recently installed the [.NET Framework 4.5.1 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/17/net-framework-4-5-1-rtm-gt-start-coding.aspx) on a Windows Server 2012 Standard machine running IIS 8.0. There is a new option to suspend application pools when they time out instead of killing off the worker process call "Idle Time-out Action". I, however, do not see this new option. I have rebooted the server and tried uninstalling and re-installing .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a new feature in IIS 8.5 rather than a feature of .NET 4.51

So you have to upgrade to Server 2012 R2 to get this feature.

Comment: that's kind of what I was afraid of, unfortunately we're using Amazon Web Services and they currently do not offer Windows Server 2012 R2.